# Is there any mapping between feature detection and current browsers?

Tags: browser-detection

Here's my problem. I have 3 days to update my company's Javascript browser detection. I'd love to take the time and implement feature detection but that's just not feasible in the allotted time. I'd like the best possible solution given the constraints.

In my mind, a Javascript library that identifies a browser based on feature detection is the best solution. For example, features A, B, and C work, so this is IE6. Is there any library that has taken this approach?

Comment: I can't find it right now but I know I have seen discussion of a common JavaScript library which tells you not only which browser but what capabilities of it are.

Comment: Do you really need to know the available features or do you need the actual browser name/Version?

Comment: I need to know the actual name/version since we only support certain ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that Mootools and Dojo have some properties set, that tell you which browser they're running in. I suppose a lot of the others do, too.

Comment: Modernizr will let you see what features are supported